# What values are stored in the padding bytes of an aligned struct/class object

Tags: c++, c, memory-alignment, memory-layout

---

```
struct Data
{
    std::uint32_t b;
    char a;
};
```

The Data type is aligned by 4 bytes, so sizeof(Data) == 8.

But what the values are in 5th-7th bytes? Is it default zero?

Comment: *Indeterminate*. Could be any seemingly random or "garbage" values.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on a few things, all detailed in the C++ standard `[dcl.init]`.

The various sections of that end up either default-initialising, zero-initialising or value-initialising depending on the storage duration, presence of various types of constructors, and so on.

Default initialising means the entire variable will be some arbitrary value while zero initialising zero-initialises all members *and sets padding bytes to zero.*

So `Data d1;` and `static Data d2;` will not necessarily have the same padding bytes.

Value initialising is a little more complex since it effectively first chooses default or zero initialisation before calling the constructor (if one exists).

---

But the bottom line is that it probably shouldn't matter. If the content of padding was important, you should be "registering" that space as real member variables so that you can use them (and have them properly initialised). Padding is very much unimportant in the "value" of a variable unless you do something crazy like `memcmp` it, or run a checksum over the entire memory block it occupies :-)

Comment: Even when I create an object with static storage duration ?

Comment: @Trevor Still indeterminate. But since it's it likely that such data (and global uninitialized data as well) is  "cleared" by `memset` (or similar) then it probably will be zero as well. But that's an implementation details that couldn't be counted on. Just don't assume there's anything other than random garbage in the padding space and you'll be fine.

Comment: @paxdiablo: so for uninitialized array that has static storage duration, the default value shall be `0` but not the padding of a struct that has static storage duration ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just want to hash a struct object, I have use `#pragma pack(1)` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I always believe it's unpredictable but still unsure in case of the object of the struct has static storage duration.

So I have made a search to see whether there is a clear mention about this in C standards and C++ standards or not (since you are asking in C and C++).

It **is** mentioned in C standards (C99, C11 and C18):

> J.1    Unspecified behavior
>
> - The value of padding bytes when storing values in structures or unions (6.2.6.1).

For C++, I could not find out it's mentioned anywhere in C++ standards.

Comment: It's all in `[dcl.init]` which covers the various scenarios for variable initialisation. See my answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo ok, I have seen it. Great information. So it's not really indeterminate like your first answer. Your edit makes my comment below so weird though :)

Comment: No, when you said you couldn't find it, I went on a deep dive into the standard. Now I have a headache and need to go get some sleep :-)